# How to resolve Warzone crashing on Xbox?

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-series-x-series-s, call-of-duty-warzone

My Warzone crashes just when I am about to join a game. I have heard this happening with other people too, specifically after the season 2 update and on Xbox, I am on a Xbox Series S. And this only happens on Caldera matches, Rebirth Island works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is actually something you can do about it rather than the usual uninstall/reinstall suggestion that most of the times is not working...

Sounds like a game issue rather than an Xbox issue but i would suggest to download **Xbox Insider Hub** on your Xbox and **submit a bug report** just right after the crash. If you do that it will collect logs and submit them to help the Xbox team get valuable information to resolve the issue.

After installing the Xbox Insider Hub you can report the issue by **holding the home button** on the controller and selecting **Report Issue**.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention I have already reinstalled the game twice but it still wont work, I will check out the Xbox Insider Hub once